# In Assassination Classroom, wouldn't killing Koro-sensei cause the earth to be destroyed?

Tags: assassination-classroom

As I understand it, the moon was destroyed when a mouse, injected with the same antibodies as Koro-sensei, was killed on the moon.

I am unclear how this could possibly lead to the belief that the world will be destroyed on March 13. Does that imply that Koro-sensei will die on March 13? What is expected to happen, that killing him would prevent?

Wouldn't killing Koro-sensei cause the same problem on Earth as killing the mouse caused on the moon? Wouldn't the solution be to keep Koro-sensei alive or ask him when he is dying to head to outer space?

Why is there a belief that killing him will stop the destruction of the Earth which would be triggered when he dies?

Is there some detail that I am missing that explains why killing him would prevent the Earth from being destroyed on March 13? Could someone summarize the details of the scenario that happens on March 13 that leads to the Earth's destruction?